# Cannot resolve modules when using Webpack's context and entry

Tags: javascript, webpack

When using [context and the entry object](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/) Webpack does not resolve any modules. This seems odd because Webpack seems to be looking for the files in the proper directory but cannot resolve them.

```
const path = require('path');

const PATHS = {
  app: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app'),
};

module.exports = {
  context: PATHS.app,
  entry: {
    app: 'app.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        resolve: {
          extensions: ['.js']
        }
      }
    ],
  },
};
```

I have the `app.js` file located at `/absolute/path/to/app`

When running Webpack the following error is thrown:

```
ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'app.js' in '/absolute/path/to/app'
```

The workaround is to remove the `context` value altogether and modify the `entry` object to:

```
  entry: {
    app: PATHS.app + '/app',
  },
```

Is there something I'm missing when using `context`and `entry` together?

Comment: Try changing your entry to `app: './app.js'`.

Comment: This fixed the issue, thank you

Comment: Great! I'll make it into an answer so the question can be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webpack and Node handle relative paths with the classic `./` notation before filenames or other paths. In other environments, relative paths without `./` are absolutely correct, but here it's required. Note that settings `context` does not affect this in any way. The outcome would still be the same. So your entry should look like this:

```
entry: {
  app: './app.js'
},
```

Unfortunately there is no official documentation covering this issue specifically, but Webpack's [documentation on entry points](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points) only uses examples containing the `./` notation.